# Exception not being caught by its catch block, then the method throws an exception of another kind

Tags: java, encryption, exception, try-catch

I'm experiencing some strange behavior but maybe I just don't completely understand how exception-handling works. I have the following piece of code:

```
public String encrypt(String msg, SecretKeySpec key) throws RuntimeException {

    try {

        System.out.println("1");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        System.out.println("2");

        ...

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.println("3");
        throw new RuntimeException("invalid key");
    }

}
```

Upon invoking, the method throws a RuntimeException and the console output is: 1

(The cipher object is an attribute of the class the method is part of and was successfully created using `Cipher.getInstance("AES", "BC")`. Here is [the documentation of the init](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#init(int,%20java.security.Key)) method where the program fails.)

Comment: *"Upon invoking, the method throws a RuntimeException..."* Okay. So  `RuntimeException` is being thrown by `init` and since it's a `RuntimeException`, not [`InvalidKeyException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/InvalidKeyException.html), the `catch` handler doesn't match, so it isn't run. So...? (Presumably the `RuntimException` you're getting contains some useful information as well. What is it?)

Comment: What exactly were you expecting? An exception is thrown by cipher.init, it is caught and in the catch block the runtimeexception is thrown.

Comment: @AndreasHartmann: No, if it were that, the OP would see 1 **and** 3. They said they only see 1, so the exception being thrown must not be `InvalidKeyException`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Exactly, "3" doesn't appear on the console. According to the docs, init throws an InvalidKeyException.

Comment: @tom: And potentially any `RuntimeException` it wants. Those need not be declared (that's their main purpose, they're *unchecked* exceptions). Again: Presumably the exception has information in it; what is it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right, I added another catch before the one I have to catch a RuntimeException, and it is executed. So the mystery is solved, a RuntimeException is thrown by init. Sorry for the stupid question, I'm still a beginner:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symptoms tell us that `init` is throwing a `RuntimeException`. Since that isn't an `InvalidKeyException`, your `catch` handler doesn't catch it.

Remember that although `init` is only documented to throw `InvalidKeyException`, it can *also* throw any `RuntimeException` it likes. `RuntimeException` doesn't have to be declared (or caught); it's an *unchecked* exception, that's its purpose.

Although you don't have to catch them, you *can* catch them if you want. Normally that's not good practice (it's normally a `RuntimeException` for a good reason), but in limited cases catching it can be appropriate.